# SortBy for one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a two tables which are linked by a one-to-many relationship. Now I need to sort the rows based on the key which I have in my first table.

For Ex

```
TeacherID    StudentID
  1               1
  1               2
  1               3
  1               4
  1               5
  1               6
  1               7
  1               8
  2               9
  2               10
  2               11
  2               12
```

If I sort the Rows based on by `teacherID`, the student id's are changing for each and every execution.

In the result set the `studentID` are changing in the random order. Now I need the `studentID`'s not to be changed.

Is there anything I can do, to solve this problem without using sort by the `studentID` column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort on both.

```
ORDER BY
  TeacherID, StudentID
```

Selecting data from any database engine without specifying an `ORDER BY` doesn't guarantee any order at all.